# how to resize image according to div tag image automatic

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to resize my image that is inside div tag according to changing my div tags size automatically.how can i achieve using j query please help us
NOTE image is inside div tag.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple add width: 100% to style. Like so:

```
<img src='image_url.jpg' style='width: 100%' alt='image_name'/>
```

Comment: I believe some older browser like it when you include `height:auto` also.

Comment: But the best practice to include all styles in css files. So remember that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code.

```
    <div id="img_box">
    <img src="path/to/horizontal_image.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
    </div>
```

Also have a look at the link below.

http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3828593.htm

http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=145288

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery:

```
$('.divSelector').find('img').css({
  'width': '100%',
  'height': '100%'
});
```